# Reading a file created using virtual filesystem JIMFS

Tags: java, java-io, virtualfilesystem, jimfs

I have created a VFS using JIMFS.

```
FileSystem virtualFS = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());
Path virtualPath = virtualFS.getPath("resources/virtualFolder");
Files.createDirectories(virtualPath);
Path refData = virtualPath.resolve("refData.csv");
System.out.println(refData);

Files.write(refData, ImmutableList.of(sData),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I am trying to read the file (refData.csv)  in another method (Path is passed to the other method).

What I have tried until now are :

```
1: new FileDataModel(new FileInputStream(Files.lines(refData)));

2: new FileDataModel((File) Files.lines(refData));

3: new FileDataModel(new File(refData));
```

Unfortunately, none of these work as of now. I understand, I am mixing the default FS with the Virtual FS.

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

How to access the file created?.

Answer (score 1):

`File` and `FileInputStream` just don't work for anything but the default file system. What you'd need is a version of `FileDataModel`'s constructor that takes a `Path` or a normal `InputStream` (you can get an `InputStream` for a `Path` using `Files.newInputStream(Path)`).

(By the way, `Files.lines` returns a `Stream`, not a `File`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.)